# Add Customer Note (comments) on billing Address and Save it

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-field

I have installed [Magebase](http://magebase.com/magento-extensions/free-magento-extension-customer-comments-in-the-checkout/) Extension for add order comment.

It is working fine, But the comment is showing on Shipping method section.

I have successfully added the comment on billing address by:

> magentoRoot}/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/magebase/checkoutcomment.xml

```
<reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
    <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="mbcomments.billing" template="magebase/checkoutcomment/shipping_comment.phtml" />
</reference>
```

By calling below code at:

> {magentoRoot}/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mbcomments.billing') ?>
```

**Problem:** How to Save this field in `Customer_note` as it is currently doing for Shipping method.

Please suggest any `observer` which can save above value.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you can use this [module](https://github.com/boldcommerce/magento2-ordercomments) OR [this](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date) one is advanced version

Comment: Thank you, but I am on version 1.9

Comment: Oh Sorry, let me find another one

Comment: try this options [1](https://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/customer-order-comment-management/), [2](https://github.com/magemaven/magento-order-comment), [3](http://magebase.com/magento-extensions/free-magento-extension-customer-comments-in-the-checkout/), [4](http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-add-order-comment-on-customer-checkout-in-magento/)